# Enabling CORS in asp.net core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

I created a simple api in .net core and trying to access that from react app, I get a CORS error. I enabled cors by following `CORS with default policy and middleware` section on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

still I get cors error in my react app. not exactly sure where I am getting it wrong.

.net core api

```
namespace React_NalONE_API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                // options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                //                 builder =>
                //               {
                //                 builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost/*",
                //                                   "https://localhost/*");
                //         });

                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost/*",
                                        "https://localhost/*");
                });
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

React app

```
 componentDidMount () {
        console.log("The component is now mounted")
        this.setState({loading : true})
        fetch('https://localhost:44391/agency')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({data, loading : false}))
      }
```

error

`Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44391/agency' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Your help is much appreciated
Thanks
R

Comment: Violate this constraint ? `Note: The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is returned.` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: where am I violating the constraint @nwpie

Comment: [HTTP/Headers/Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) mentioned that `localhost` (or localhost:8080) will fit the schema, not localhost/* nor localhost/ . Hope helps.

Answer (score -1):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware), you could know that:

> Note: The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the
>   URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is
>   returned.

For your requirement,it seems you want to allow CORS requests from all origins with any scheme (`http` or `https`),I suggest that you could use [`AllowAnyOrigin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-allowed-origins):

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
        });
```

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-allowed-origins

Another way is to change like below:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44391",
                                        "http://localhost:44391");
                });
        });
```

Comment: does my url contain trailing slash. I dont understand where is the slash?

Comment: my url which is https://localhost:44391/agency does not have a trailing slash

Comment: Tailing slash means this line in your startup.cs:`builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost/*","https://localhost/*");`.It could not be `/*`.You need to change this line to `builder.AllowAnyOrigin();`.